# Adjacency List in graph

Tags: c++, graph-theory, adjacency-list

Hi I am try to implement a graph using adjacency list using following code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_map>
using namespace std;

class graph{
    public:
    vector<int> adj[10000];

void insert(int u,int v, bool direction) {
    adj[u].push_back(v);

    if(direction==1) {
        adj[v].push_back(u);
    }

}

void print(int n) {


       for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++) {
            cout<<i<<"->";
            for(auto j : adj[i]) {
                cout<<j<<",";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    
};
int main( ) {
    
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter no of node"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
cout<<"enter edges "<<endl;
int m;
cin>>m;
graph g;
for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
    int u, v;
    cin>>u>>v;
    g.insert(u,v,1);
}
g.print(n);
return 0;
```

}

But the problem with this code is that it will give correct answer only in the case when my node start from 0 in a continuous manner(0,1,2,3). But when I try to print adjacency list of this graph:

[image]

Then it is giving this output:

[image]

Can somebody tell me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edges you are adding aren't the same as the graph i picture, you are inputting edge `1, 3` instead of edge `1, 5`.

Answer (score 0):

It's printing the `0` because you started that for loop from `i = 0` and it doesn't print node `5` for the same reason (the loop ends at `4` because you will have `i < 4 + 1`.

```
void print(int n) {
             //↓↓↓ HERE
       for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++) {
            cout<<i<<"->";
            for(auto j : adj[i]) {
                cout<<j<<",";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Here is how I would change your code:
First, I changed the `print()` function a little (added the `if()` to see if the current row is empty and I changed the `int n` parameter to `int maximum` which will hold the highest value node so we know when to stop the `for`).

```
void print(int maximum)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=maximum; i++)
        {
            if(!adj[i].empty())
            {
                cout<<i<<"->";

                for(auto j : adj[i])
                {
                    cout<<j<<",";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, in `main()` I added the `maximum` and `aux` variables in order to store the aforementioned highest value node. And I also changed the `g.print(n)` to `g.print(maximum)`.

```
int main( )
{

    int n, maximum = 0, aux;
    cout<<"Enter no of node"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"enter edges "<<endl;
    int m;
    cin>>m;
    graph g;
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        int u, v;
        cin>>u>>v;
        g.insert(u,v,1);

        aux = max(u, v);
        maximum = max(maximum, aux);
    }
    g.print(maximum);
    return 0;
}
```

However, I might not be Terry A. Davis, but I know that if you say you have 4 nodes, those 4 nodes will be 1 2 3 and 4. And I also know that any graph related problem will have nodes starting from 1, therefore every `for loop` would start from `i = 1`, or at least that's how I was taught. The way you did it might be correct too, but I am not sure.